# Cant load "TheBloke/Mistral-7B-v0.1-GGUF" model on GPU

Tags: python, ctransformers

My code

```
from ctransformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Mistral-7B-v0.1-GGUF", model_file='mistral-7b-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf', model_type='mistral', hf=True)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
device = 'cuda:0'

prompt = 'text'
model_inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
model_inputs.to(device)
model.to(device)
```

But model is still on cpu
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtX7K.png)

I've also tried

```
model = model.to(device)
```

I've tried to make device type with torch

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the [`ctransformers` library](https://github.com/marella/ctransformers), which makes GPU-based inference a little tricky. As noted [here](https://github.com/marella/ctransformers#gpu), you must specify the `gpu_layers` parameter.

The following snippet should work if you're using the *regular* [transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) library.

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

# see: https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1#troubleshooting
assert transformers.__version__ >= 4.34.0

MODEL_NAME = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1"
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# [1.] Load model and move to GPU
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
model = model.to(DEVICE)

# [2.] Do inference
input_data = "..."
encoded_input = tokenizer(input_data, 
                          padding=True, 
                          truncation=True, 
                          return_tensors="pt").to(DEVICE)
resp = model(**encoded_input)
```

Info is available [here](https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1/discussions/63) on GPU sizing for this model.